# How to load ogg file in c?

Tags: c, openal, oggvorbis

I'm learning about audio with openal and trying to load ogg files into memory so I can play them with openal. I have been searching for a library to load ogg files and the best one I found was [this one](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_vorbis.c), it has no dependences. But the documentation is messy and I can't find a decent tutorial-example online.
All I want to know is how to load an ogg and get something that I can actually send to a openal buffer.

**Q: If I have this call:**

```
stb_vorbis_decode_filename(const char *filename, int *channels, int *sample_rate, short **output);
```

**it should decode "filename" and store the data into "output". So I can send it to openal right?**
It's not lack of research, after hours of reading I can't really get how it works. If there's another library to load ogg files easily then please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, why not just try that command. As I understand nothings.org/stb_vorbis/samples/sample.c, it reads a file, "converts it to short" (?? I guess this means "16 bit samples"), and updates the *pointer to* with this memory. To know if that is enough to " get something that I can actually send to a openal buffer" depends on what OpenAL accepts.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it?  What results/error did you get?  Perhaps something like this:

```
int channels;
int sample_rate;
short * output;
int rc = stb_vorbis_decode_filename("somefile.ogg", &channels, &sample_rate, &output);
if (rc == -1) fprintf(stderr, "oops\n");
```

Comment: I did try, but I'm not sure that it gives me the data I need to send to openal. Anyway, I solved it by A) Actually playing around with openal. and B) Using sdl_mixer to load ogg files. I am using sdl to get the window running anyway, so sdl_mixer suits perfectly. I just wanted to avoid dependencies